# Filter json object based on key

Tags: javascript, json

My json object looks like this

```
Object
  A:Object
  B:Object
  C:Object
  D Object
  E:Object
  F:Object
  __proto__:Object
```

I want to get only `D and E` from this json object based on key. New json object should only include `D and E`. how to acheive this?

Comment: This question about filtering a single JSON abject however in duplicate tag question is about JSON array. 
Need to remove duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function copyObjectProps(source, keys) {
   let newObject = {}
   keys.forEach(function(key) {
     newObject[key] = source[key]
   })
   return newObject
}
```

And use it like:

```
let filteredObject = copyObjectProps(yourObject, ['D', 'E'])
```

Comment: this is the best way to do it, but I wouldn't use arrow function because it's not widely supported yet.

Comment: Where I work, we use babel that's why I end up using ES6 everywhere. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`Object['D']` and `Object['E']` will give you direct access to corresponding objects.

You can create new object using..

```
var newObj = { D : Object['D'], E : Object['E']}
```

Use original object name instead of `Object` for accessing.

Using `JSON.stringify(newObj);` to can get the new JSON.

Comment: D Earthing is a typo. i have changed now.

Answer (score 0):

Filter only applies to arrays. Therefore, you need to define a new variable and run a for loop.

```
var mynewobject ={};
for (var key in myobject)
{
   if (...) // apply your condition here
      mynewobject[key] = myobject[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use underscrore(http://underscorejs.org/) or loadash(https://lodash.com/).

The have methods like _.pick to pick specific nodes.

many more options are also available.